# jQuery impromptu: Form getting submitted even before Yes or No ic clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) for submitting one of my forms.
In the above mentioned URL I am using the Example 2.

Now when i try incorporating the same in my form submission, the form is getting submitted even before i clcik on the yes / no button.

I am using the following line of code for the form submit

```
<input type="image" name="delete" src="images/delete.png" onclick="$.prompt('Are you sure??',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false } })">
```

I am sure I am missing out on something.
Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Alloi

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="image" name="delete" src="images/delete.png" onclick="$.prompt('Are you sure??',{ buttons: { Ok: $('form#foo').submit(), Cancel: false } }); return false;">
```

Even better, try to make your JS unobstrusive:

```
<input type="image" name="delete" src="images/delete.png" />
```

```
$('input[name=delete]').click(function() {
    $.prompt('Are you sure??',{
        buttons: {
            Ok: $('form#foo').submit(),
            Cancel: false
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That `Ok` property will cause the form to be submitted *right away*. Need to wrap that in a function. Also, does jQuery ensure that returning `false` from the image button's `click` event will prevent the form submission? Because that's not reliable cross-browser behavior.

Comment: @T.J., you're right about the function wrapping, I'm unfamiliar with the plugin so it slipped from me. Returning false will prevent the form from submitting when clicking that button, but it will not prevent submitting it on enter press, for example.

Comment: @Tata: I think actually the `true` is just to tell the plugin to show the `Ok` button; there's a separate thing about callbacks. (I don't know the plugin either, just looked at the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

Impromptu doesn't wait before execution. So you shouldn't submit before user confirms operation.

**Use like this:**

```
<input type="image" name="delete" src="images/delete.png" onclick="confirmAndDelete()">
```

**with the javascript function:**

```
function confirmAndDelete(){

    var deleteFunc = function()
    {
        $('form#foo').submit();
    };

    $.prompt("Are you sure?", 
             {
               title: "Delete Confirm",
               buttons: { "Yes": true, "No": false },
               submit: function (e, val, m, f) {                            
                            if (val == true)
                                deleteFunc();
                            else
                                console.log('Delete not confirmed!');
                        }
              });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancy prompts like this show a message on/over the page, but they *don't* suspend execution like `alert` and `confirm` do. (This is what they mean on [the docs page](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) when they say *" This is not intended to be a modal replacement..."*) So although you're showing the prompt, the form submission continues.

The usual way to handle this is to show the prompt but cancel the form submission, and then submit the form programmatically if the user says "Yes."

Basically, you:

- Set up a submit handler on the form so that it cancels the submission if it's told to
- Set up the image click to tell the form to cancel the submission and show the prompt instead
- Set up a handler on the prompt's "Yes" button to submit the form